# Django FileField not saving

Tags: python, django

There are existing posts here which deal with the same problem as mine however, none offer a proper solution for my problem. 
I am working on a project with multiple models say A,B,C,D and E. Three of those have FileFields in them. I have made changes to settings.py MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL to get FileField working. It works perfectly on 2 models and saves to the proper location and everything. For the third model, the same line

```
models.FileField( upload_to='media/documents', null=True, blank=True)
```

doesn't save the file to the location. The httpd error logs are blank. This third model is an inline model. Anyone has any ideas as to why this model would suddenly 'glitch'. Below are the httpd access logs

```
192.168.45.139 - - [06/Aug/2018:15:50:01 +0000] "POST /admin/midb/job/3027/change/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
192.168.45.139 - - [06/Aug/2018:15:50:01 +0000] "GET /admin/midb/job/3027/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 205520
192.168.45.139 - - [06/Aug/2018:15:50:03 +0000] "GET /nested_admin/server-data.js HTTP/1.1" 200 288
192.168.45.139 - - [06/Aug/2018:15:50:03 +0000] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3185
```

Edit: Added models. The first two 'work' while the last one doesnt. The first two are by themselves while the third model is inlined. This is being saved in Django admin.

```
class CustomerPDF(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=300)
    other_members = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=250)
    institute = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=300)
    cr_system = models.ForeignKey(
        Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    paper = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=300)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True,
                          max_length=300)
    year = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=150)
    journal = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=300)
    tags = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    file_pdf_customer = models.FileField(
        upload_to='media/documents', null=True, blank=True)
    file_pdf_customer.allow_tags = True

class MarketTrends(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=300)
    institute = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
    paper = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=300)
    year = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=15)
    tags = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    file_pdf_market = models.FileField(
        upload_to='media/documents', null=True, blank=True)
    file_pdf_market.allow_tags = True

class TripReport(models.Model):
    service_name = models.ForeignKey(ServiceSupport, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trip_description = models.CharField(
        "Description", max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    files = models.FileField(
        upload_to='media/documents', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you add those models to the post?

Comment: Where are you doing the upload? In the admin, or a separate page? If so post the relevant view, form and template.

Comment: Note though you usually don't need "media" in the upload_to location.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I added the models but I am not sure if that would help :(

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is being done in the admin.

Comment: I've copied your three models (bare minimum, without foreign keys) into a fresh project and they all work fine, added in a generic admin view `admin.site.register(TripReport)`. Maybe the problem is in your customization of your admin view?

Answer (score 3):

Did you add these code in template?

```
<form  method="post" id="myform"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```